# I node.js how to update the value of an already required module

Tags: node.js, caching, module

I am a little step away of a very simple database cache system with nodejs. I don't want to install a complete data handling solution like Redis, I just need to read and cache data and sometimes reload it from DB, without any handling feature, so I implemented this:

- In my cache module, for the first evaluation I query DB and return the result in module.exports
- So all following `require` for this module will return the cached value instead of querying the DB again >> I made it so far and I divided by 5 the consumed time.
- Then I need a function to reload the module >> I failed there...

I feel like I am a very little step away to succeed, here is what I implemented (I run node.js v14.15.1,  I simplified all code to make it more readable...):

Firstly I made the module to export the permissions by itself, it works, I got the list of permissions when I require the module:

```
/** FILE cached_permissions.js **/        
const permissionModel = require("../models/permission.model")

getPermissionsAtInit = async () => {
  return await permissionModel.find().exec()
}
module.exports = getPermissionsAtInit()
```

Then, the classic route file:

```
/** FILE permissions.route.js **/    

// Permission service
const PermissionService = require("../services/permission.service")

// Routes to get permissions from DB
app.get("/api/permissions", async (req, res) => { 
    res.send(await PermissionService.getPermissionsFromDB()} )

// Route to get permission from cache
app.get("/api/cached-permissions", async (req, res) => { 
    res.send(await PermissionService.getCachedPermissions()})

// Route to reset permission cache
app.get("/api/reset-cache", async (req, res) => { 
    await PermissionService.resetCache()
    res.send("cache reseted")})
```

Here is the permission service module

```
/** FILE permission.service.js */
// Module with cached permissions
const cachedPermissions = require("./cached_permissions.js")

// Module to query the db
const permissionModel = require("../models/permission.model")

class PermissionService {

  static getPermissionsFromDB = async () => {
    // Mongoose query to get data from DB
    return await permissionModel.find().exec()
  }

  static getCachedPermissions = () => { 
    // Directly returns value from cached module
    return cachedPermissions 
  }

  static resetCache = async () => {
    // firstly we delete the cached module
    delete require.cache[require.resolve("./cached_permissions.js")]
    
    // then we require again the module to force the re-cache
    require("./cached_permissions.js")
  }
}

module.exports = PermissionService
```

So I can run the following:

- http call /api/permissions >> returns the list of permissions from DB ~50ms
- http call /api/cached-permissions >> returns the same list of permissions ~10ms
- I manually update data in mongoDB
- 2nd http call to /api/permissions >> returned updated data
- 2nd http call to /api/cached-permissions >> returned first set of data

So for so good, this is the expected behavior

- Then http call to /api/reset-cache
- 3rd call to /api/cached-permissions >> still return not updated data

I know the /api/reset-cache is done because I console.log `Object.keys(require.cache)`, and I can see it deleted after the `delete require.cache[...]` and I can see it appear again after the new `require("./cached_permissions.js")`.

But anyway, when I call again /api/cached-permissions, the value has not been updated. It feels like the `const cachedPermissions = require("./cached_permissions.js")` from my file permission.service.js has been loaded only once when the server starts when the permissions.route.js file require the permission.service.js file, and not each time a route is called, even if I reload a specific module.

Do you know a way I could reload the module in already loaded file, or update the value of a module in an alreay loaded file or some other way to make this work? I feel like I am a very little step away of a very simple DB cache system...

Comment: Do not abuse the nodejs module cache for caching data. Store the data in your `PermissionService` instance, and manipulate it like any other property.

Comment: "*It feels like the `const cachedPermissions = require("./cached_permissions.js")` from my file permission.service.js has been loaded only once when the server starts, and not each time a route is called*" - well that's exactly what your code is written to do. `cachedPermissions` is a `const`ant in your *permission.service.js* module, and you never update that constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels like the `const cachedPermissions = require("./cached_permissions.js")` from my file permission.service.js has been loaded only once when the server starts, and not each time a route is called

Well that's exactly what your code is written to do. The `cachedPermissions` is a `const`ant in your *permission.service.js* module, and you never update that constant. If instead you would do

```
static getCachedPermissions = () => { 
  // Directly returns value from cached module
  return require("./cached_permissions.js"); 
}
```

it would load the module (from the module cache, or evaluate the module code if fresh) on every request.

---

But really there's no reason to use the module cache for this. A simple variable in your permission service module would suffice:

```
/* permission.service.js */

const permissionModel = require("../models/permission.model"); // Module to query the db

async function getPermissionsFromDB() {
  // Mongoose query to get data from DB
  return await permissionModel.find().exec()
}

let cachedPermissions = getPermissionsFromDB();

module.exports.getPermissionsFromDB = getPermissionsFromDB;

module.exports.getCachedPermissions = () => cachedPermissions;

module.exports.resetCache = () => {
  cachedPermissions = getPermissionsFromDB();
};
```

Comment: Ok, do not abuse module cache system, I get it! Your answer works like a charm! But there is a point I  don't understand: in your initial affectation of `cachedPermissions = getPermissionsFromDB()`, the called function `getPermissionsFromDB()` is an async function, I don't understand how your call without await works as wanted.

Comment: Anyway, it works very well, I am very happy with this, now I have the call to cachedPermissions that takes less than 10ms instead  of 60ms for permissions from DB! And since it's used for role management, it'is used in ALL routes as a middleware, so this is a crazy performance gap for the whole app. Thanks a lot Bergi!

Comment: @ThomasPerrin It works exactly the same as your `getPermissionsAtInit()` function - it returns a promise and stores that in the variable.